# drop down menu showing after image

Tags: html, css

I am setting up a navigation menu with one link as a drop down, then an image to like a facebook page. It's working as expected, however it's showing the drop down as the last link, not the end like I want. See my code below:

```css
ul.nav  {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffd903;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffd903,#fffcee);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #ffd903,#fffcee);
}
    
li.navigation {
    float: left;
}

li.navigation a, .drop {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    
li.navigation a:hover, .submenu:hover .drop, footer a:hover {
    background: #56d019;
}
    
li.submenu {
    display: inline-block;
}
    
.submenu-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffd903;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffd903,#fffcee);
    background: linear-gradient( #ffd903,#fffcee);
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
    
.submenu-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
    
.submenu-content a:hover {
    background-color: #56d019
}
    
.submenu:hover .submenu-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="navigation"><a href="about.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="submenu">
            <a class="drop" href="employees.html">Employees</a>
            <div class="submenu-content">
                <a href="nora.html" title="Nora Jones">Nora Jones</a>
                <a href="carolyn.html" title="Carolyn Pennington">Carolyn Pennington</a>
                <a href="samuel.html" title="Samuel Griffiths">Samuel Griffiths</a>
                <a href="alexandra.html" title="Alexandra Smith">Alexandra Smith</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation"><a href="report.html" title="Report">Report</a>
        <li class="navigation"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" title="Find us on Facebook!"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Find us on Facebook"/> </a>
    </ul> 
</nav><br/>
```

Could someone please advise where I'm going wrong? I had it working correctly until I had to change the lists as having classes and now I'm not sure what I messed up.

Comment: _“Could someone please advise where I'm going wrong?”_ - all your other list items are floated to the left, but this one is not floated and only set to inline-block. You need to either float them all, _or_ display them all as inline-block - mixing those two does not make much sense.

Comment: ^ you're right, it didn't. Switching them all to inline-block worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffd903;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffd903, #fffcee);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #ffd903, #fffcee);
}

li.navigation {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.navigation a,
.drop {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.navigation a:hover,
.submenu:hover .drop,
footer a:hover {
  background: #56d019;
}

li.submenu {
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffd903;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffd903, #fffcee);
  background: linear-gradient( #ffd903, #fffcee);
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.submenu-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.submenu-content a:hover {
  background-color: #56d019
}

.submenu:hover .submenu-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="navigation"><a href="about.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="navigation"><a href="contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="submenu">
      <a class="drop" href="employees.html">Employees</a>
      <div class="submenu-content">
        <a href="nora.html" title="Nora Jones">Nora Jones</a>
        <a href="carolyn.html" title="Carolyn Pennington">Carolyn Pennington</a>
        <a href="samuel.html" title="Samuel Griffiths">Samuel Griffiths</a>
        <a href="alexandra.html" title="Alexandra Smith">Alexandra Smith</a>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation"><a href="report.html" title="Report">Report</a></li>
      <li class="navigation">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" title="Find us on Facebook!"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Find us on Facebook" /></a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</nav><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add navigation class to submenu in order to make it float left,
check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanopd1j/) and let me know if this solve your issue, also there is a minor change but still important, it's to add `li.navigation` before `.submenu-content a` as follows:

```
li.navigation .submenu-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```